# Skin Modifier 'Skin Resize, Ctrl-A' Not Working!

Tags: modifiers

Just started learning about the skin modifier and immediately came across this issue. The shortcut to scaling is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>, but this error messages pops up. Does anyone have a solution for me?[image]

I already tried rearranging the modifiers, but the same problem exists. Does it have to do with my using Cycles instead of Blender Render?

Comment: I could not reproduce it, sorry... If you wish, you could upload your test file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, then paste the provided link in your question's text.

Comment: Shortcuts for modelling tools and modifiers don't depend on render engine, in particular default ones, so they couldn't provide this behaviour. Do you use some custom key binding sets? In this case Ctrl+A does something else.

Comment: @MrZak I already checked the shortcut keys and indeed, 3D View Skin resize is assigned as Ctrl A!

Comment: @m.ardito I didn't save the file, but all I did was in a new scene, created a plane, merged all vertices to center to create a single vertex, extruded a few times, and added the modifiers above. When trying to adjust the skin resize, the Ctrl A buttons gave me those errors! I had followed a tutorial for this and I followed it step by step until this happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one test and see what happens: place the surface subdivision modifier above skin modifier. Sometimes, modifiers clash with each other, so you have to test them by moving them up and down within the panel. 
If that does not work, try moving mirrior modifier down. If nothing, try applying surface subdivision. 
If that fails, I hope somebody else will have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac it's <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are in *vertex select mode*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.