# Skin modifier not giving any volume to my mesh

Tags: modifiers

Beginner here. I'm trying to follow up [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/4SUFECKR5wA?t=310). Unfortunately, I'm stuck when it comes to use the skin modifier to thicken up the tree.

I've seen potential related topics ([1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227719/skin-modifier-not-working), [2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118693/skin-modifier-skin-resize-ctrl-a-not-working), and the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/skin.html)). But couldn't find anything useful in either of these. In every tutorial I watch about the skin modifer, as soon as someone has 2 connected vertices and apply the skin modifier, there's a shape. In my case nothing, even if I try to ctrl + A to scale it.

I'm on latest version of Blender 3.4.1.

Here's what I'm doing:

- Create a tree by extruding vertices

[image]

- Add skin modifier

[image]

- If I tab out and go back to object mode, I can see something weird going on, like the mesh is dotted...

[image]

I can see that the modifier is here, but nothing is shown in the view despite having that modifier shown

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: hello could you please share your file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vfdqnDpC-njMetizIvstE3Edeiq_N-5w/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the scale in *Object* mode. Then to control the skin thickness, select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Daaamn, thank you so much! I've seen warnings in so many tutorials telling everyone don't forget to apply, or it may behave weirdly. And I've been quite careful about it since. But it finally bite me. All working great now, thanks!